# DataFrame length in pyspark structred streeming

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am wondering is there a way to know the length of a pyspark dataframe in structured streeming?
In effect i am readstreeming a dataframe from kafka and seeking a way to know the size of resulted dataframe as i do different filter on that in different steps.
I am calculating df size or length in each window using groupby on the timestamp column as follows:

```
sqlFunctions.window(col("etimestamp"), "30 seconds", "30 seconds")
```

and can get what i want. But it seems strange to me for counting (a primary need) we should do this. Moreover, if for example my primary need was to groupby another column, it means that i should first groupby that column and then on the result dataframe i should apply another groupby! Is there any way to be aware of the number of results of a query directly?
Using the `df.count()` method i receive this error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

The code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myapp") \
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1") \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_version) \
.option("subscribe", "mytopic") \
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
.load()

df2 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
jsonSchema = (
    StructType()
        .add("fwd", IntegerType()),
        .add("st", LongType()),
)
print(df.count(), df2.count())

query = df2\
.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.format("console") \
.start()
```

Comment: just do df.count() which returns number of rows which equal df length.

Comment: That does not work with structured streaming. I have tried that.

Comment: what? either you don't know what spark structured streaming is or you don't know how to call count on dataframe in spark scala.

Comment: show me the exact code where you apply count please.

Comment: spark structured streaming documentation shows you use of count on dataframe so you dont know what you talk about https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Updated my question with the error with .count().

Comment: Your problem is not related to count method which is not lazy. Your structured streaming boilerplate is wrong and you incorrectlynstsrt spark application. Do you use read stream etc? Follow documentation or show whole application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception has occurred: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException 'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;\nkafka'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472860/exception-has-occurred-pyspark-sql-utils-analysisexception-queries-with-stream)

Comment: Actually it seems meaningful to me that there is not a size for df because the stream. Agree?

Comment: no, i dont agree. count is not lazy operation. you are not starting your application correctly so you are failling at the initial step.

Comment: just add: query = df2 \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239527/discussion-between-keramat-and-dariusz-krynicki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spark documentation, the suggested way:

> count() - Cannot return a single count from a streaming Dataset.
> Instead, use ds.groupBy().count() which returns a streaming Dataset
> containing a running count.

Note that, you should use
`complete`
mode.